# How can I SSH login from RStudio terminal

Tags: powershell, ssh, rstudio, hpc

I want to make a SSH login to a high performance computer from the terminal in RStudio so I can execute my code by highlighting it in RStudio script and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> directly. However, the RStudio terminal has a problem with SSH because of a [key issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/966). Did anyone successfully SSH login from the RStudio terminal and could tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51866922/ssh-keygen-does-not-find-ssh-askpass) . After setting Command Prompt as the terminal, and  opening the terminal, we have to type

```
set DISPLAY=
```

and then run the ssh login. It will then ask for the key. set DISPLAY = needs to be typed every single time you want to connect the R terminal to ssh.

I hope this question and answer helps anyone else, if not, feel free to suggest deleting it.